# Why is the gravitational potential energy always increasing?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential-energy

Gravitational potential goes on increasing with distance, but I've also learnt that the gravitational potential is maximum at a certain distance if we consider Earth to be in 0 potential.

If the object doesn't lie in the gravitational field, then how does the potential energy still increase? Also, the further the object travels, the lesser is the gravitational force,right,then what is the reason for this increment in potential energy?
I am really confused!

Comment: What do you mean by the Earth being in $0$ potential? Potential due to what? The gravitational potential always depends on the distance between *two* objects.

Answer (score 1):

There is no maximum gravitational potential. Gravitational attraction decreases with distance by the inverse square law; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law , but it never becomes zero. So with increasing distance the additional gravitational potential increases less and less but it never becomes zero additional potential. In other words the farther away two masses are from each other the farther they have to be accelerated towards each other by their gravitational attraction which never becomes zero.